# Can we change android smartphone bluetooth role to slave

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

By default all smartphones operate Bluetooth master mode so they can connect to several devices. For my project, I have a requirement to change Bluetooth role of the android smartphone to "Slave". This is needed so another master (Smartphone) could connect to it. The question is 
Can we change the BT role on a phone from master to slave?
Can this change be done by an app or would this be a firmware / ROM level change
Has any similar implementation been done.

Any help / advise appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set your Android device to be a slave, you can use the [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_GB) app for this. As soon as you launch the app, you'll have three tabs at the top, namely **Scanner**, **Bonded**, and **Advertiser**. Simply select **Advertiser** and add your **Display name** as well as **Advertising Record** if you want to.

I hope this helps.