# How to use Android Device as a BLE(bluetooth low energy)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am going to use Android device as a BLE device so that it can be communicated with BLE by connecting with BLE libraries.
If I use BLE libraries in app, app can search and connect BLE devices without any problem, but the goal is to make android device as a BLE device so that other android or iPhone can detect it as BLE device.
I have some troubles in it and not able to find helpful data from google.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

So you want your Android device to act as a **peripheral**/**GATT server** in order for it to be discoverable and connectable by remote devices. This is doable and you can follow the examples here to do this:-

- [Bluetooth Low Energy on Android, Part 1](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/) (Check **Advertising** part)
- [Can we change android smartphone bluetooth role to slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570695/can-we-change-android-smartphone-bluetooth-role-to-slave/59730545#59730545)
- [Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)